# C++ inheriting a class vs creating a member

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, member-variables

Let say I have a class with multiple methods.
I like to separate into multiple classes.
Can I inherit that classes or can I create member with that classes?
Which one is more efficient and usable?

Let's say i have this below class

```
class ClassRoom {
    vector<int> BoysIds;
    vector<int> GirlsIds;
public:
    void RegisterBoy(int i);
    void RegisterGirl(int i);
    int GetTotalBoys();
    int GetTotalGirls();
};
```

And i have separated into multiple classes like below

```
class Boys {
    vector<int> BoysIds;
public:
    void RegisterBoy(int i);
    int GetTotalBoys();
};

class Girls {
    vector<int> GirlsIds;
public:
void RegisterGirl(int i);
int GetTotalGirls();
};
```

inheriting a class is more efficient?

```
class ClassRoom : public Boys, public Girls {
};
```

creating a member is more efficient?

```
class ClassRoom {
public:
    Boys m_boys;
    Girls m_girls;
};
```

Comment: What does "efficient" mean to you? Is there something that prevents you from trying all the alternative approach, and then determining whichever one is more "efficient", using whatever definition of "efficient" is important to you?

Comment: `inheriting a class is more efficient?` Everything is a tradeoff, without knowing what you are optimizing, there is no way to tell which is more efficient(time? space? complexity? mainability? expressiveness? cleverness?). The need to discriminate between boys and girls at class level is a little concerning at first glance as well, highest I would allow myself would be `Student`.

Comment: It depends. From a design perspective inheritance (at least, `public` inheritence) represents "is a type of" relationships (e.g. a  dog is an animal, so a class `Dog` may inherit from `Animal`) whereas aggregation (membership) represents ownership or associations between classes (e.g.  a `Car` may contain a `SteeringWheel`, and have a pointer to an `Owner` (since a car is often associated with an owner, but the owner is not really a part of the car).  Using inheritance when membership makes more design sense tends to make your code harder to understand, and harder to get right.

Answer (score 3):

Both multiple inheritance and members are efficient.  However, it is probably better style to use members here, not multiple inheritance, unless you have a really good reason for it.  Just splitting the class up, without any other justification, is probably not a good enough reason to use multiple inheritance.

As a general rule, multiple inheritance should be avoided unless there is a good reason why you need to use it.

Also, in recent decades, having members (your class "has-a" `Boys` and a `Girls`) is preferred to inheritance (your class "is-a" `Boys` and a `Girls`) unless there is a good reason to do otherwise.

You can still make your members separate classes, without using multiple inheritance.  However, if you want to define your public methods in the separate classes, you will need to forward them manually.

Comment: Also I'd like to suggest that perhaps the OP wants a `Gender` enum, and then a `GenderGroup` class that wraps a vector and has a gender flag based on that enum. `boys_group` and `girls_group` can just be instances of `GenderGroup`.